# Unable to access URL by deploying .war file in JBoss7.1

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0, spring-3

I have developed an application using Spring 3.0 with Maven and JPA 2.1, and created the .war file using maven.The war deployed on Jboss7.1 successfully but when I'm trying to access the URL 
HTTP://localhost:9999/project/index.html it download a file of 1kb and didn't call the controller.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Your jboss-web.xml might not have the right context root or maybe the port is wrong or your hosts file isn't set up for localhost as 127.0.0.1.  Could be any number of things that are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lots of R&D , I conclude below reasons of problem :

1. First check for the Port no. on which application running.
2. Check your META-INF folder for correct values of Persistent.xml and project related information

```
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyApplication"/>
</manifest>
```

3. check for data-source created inside the Application server and mapped in spring *-servlet.xml or persistence.xml .
4. Check for Appropriate jar files in pom.xml

Note: In my case I don't need jboss-web.xml